# Expresión regular que acepte letras y números pero que no acepte solo números

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy trabajando con react y necesito una expresión regular que acepte letras y números, pero que no acepte solo números

```
    nombresEGZ: {
      message: "Letras, números, &, y sin espacios al principio y final",
      rule: (val, params, validator) => {
        return (
          validator.helpers.testRegex(
            val,
            /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d10-9&]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9&\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9&\u00f1\u00d1]+$/g
          ) && params.indexOf(val) === -1
        );
      },
    }
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, porfavor revisa el [tour] y de paso lee [ask] para poder ayudarte y que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Pega el código que llevas para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear dos expresiones en vez de una que valide todo. Osea, una que valide que tu valor contiene números y otra para letras.

He simplificado tu regex para el ejemplo.

```
validator.helpers.testRegex(val, /^[a-zA-Z]+$/g) && validator.helpers.testRegex(val,
  /[0-9]+/g) && params.indexOf(val) === -1
```